# Alexa Skill Static Audio File implementation

Tags: audio, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I have been playing around with this project from git, and so far so good.

https://github.com/bespoken/streamer

I would like to enhance it to play a long form static audio file when the user asks for it. For example, if the user asks for "Ask Streamer to Play the National Anthem", I would like to just play just that file. Does anyone have a good idea on the best way to implement this simple thing?

I tried a few approaches and I am having trouble getting the end result. For one, I do not want the data of static file to be saved on dynamodb, but still want the podcast information to be saved.

I added an Intent for 'Anthem', and sample utterances for that intent. In the constants.js file, I added a new "STATIC_MODE", and tried to replicate how PLAY_MODE is implemented through out

Here is the issue I am running into, whenever I stop the Anthem file from playing, and later invoke the Podcast Player, it starts playing The Anthem, instead of podcasts.I tried commenting out the saveState in audioEventHandlers.js for the STATIC_MODE handler, yet, when I try to play podcast, it still plays the Anthem when I ask for play podcast.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is probably bad, but I have never coded in javascript, just tried to follow the git project to enhance the functionality to my liking.

Answer (score 2):

I created the Streamer project that you reference. In the interest of providing a simpler example on how to use the Alexa AudioPlayer, I also created this project:
https://github.com/bespoken/super-simple-audio-player

I believe it happens to do exactly what you requested, which is it simply plays a single, static audio file. I created this because I wanted a have a less complicated example to show people how the AudioPlayer works. Hope you find it helpful!

Comment: John, Thank you so much! Your streamer project has immensely helped me understand Alexa Skills building a bit :) 

I guess, I am trying to get to the combination of the simple audio player and the one that also plays the itunes rss feed. I will try to see how far I can get. Let me know if you have any pointers or suggestions on how I can get there.

Comment: Ram, I think you already found it, but our [streamer](https://github.com/bespoken/streamer) fits that bill. It's a bit more complicated, but supports playing back an RSS feed. Good luck with it!